# PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint causes errors

Tags: postgresql, insert

I am new to postgresql and have a question about multiple column unique constraint.

I got this error when tried to add rows to the table:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "i_rb_on"
DETAIL:  Key (a_fk, b_fk)=(296, 16) already exists.
```

I used this code (short version):

```
INSERT INTO rb_on (a_fk, b_fk) SELECT a.pk, b.pk FROM A, B WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rb_on WHERE a_fk=a.pk AND b_fk=b.pk);
```

`i_rb_on` is unique constraint / columns `(a_fk, b_fk)`.

It seems that my `WHERE NOT EXISTS` doesn't provide a protection against the duplicate key error for this kind of unique key.

UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO tabA (mark_done, log_time, tabB_fk, tabC_fk) 
SELECT FALSE, '2003-09-02 04:05:06', tabB.pk, tabC.pk FROM tabB, tabC, tabD, tabE, tabF 
WHERE (tabC.sf_id='SUMMER' AND tabC.sf_status IN(0,1) 
       AND tabE.inventory_status=0) 
 AND tabF.tabD_fk=tabD.pk 
 AND tabD.tabE_fk=tabE.pk 
 AND tabE.tabB_fk=tabB.pk 
 AND tabF.tabC_fk=tabC.pk 
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM tabA 
                 WHERE tabB_fk=tabB.pk AND tabC_fk=tabC.pk);
```

In tabA unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i_tabA
  ON tabA
  USING btree
  (tabB_fk , tabC_fk );
```

Only one row (of many) must be inserted into the tabA.

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE NOT EXISTS` *never* provides proper protection against a unique violation. It only seems to most of the time. The `WHERE NOT EXISTS` can run concurrently with another insert, so the row is still inserted multiple times and all but one of the inserts causes a unique violation.

For that reason it's often better to just run the insert and let the violation happen if the row already exists.

I can't help you with the exact problem described unless you show the data (as SQL `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`s) and the real query.

BTW, please don't use old style `A, B` joins. Use `A INNER JOIN B ON (...)`. It makes it easier to tell which join conditions are supposed to apply to which parts of the query, and harder to forget a join condition. You seem to have done that; you're attempting to insert a cartesian product. I suspect it's just an editing mistake in the query.

Comment: "just run the insert and let the violation happen": It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission.

Answer (score 0):

I added LIMIT 1 to the end: ...WHERE tabB_fk=tabB.pk AND tabC_fk=tabC.pk) LIMIT1 ;
and it did the trick.

I created a function with LIMIT 1 and ...EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN ... and it also worked.

But when LIMIT 1  and "NOT EXISTS" are used, I think, it is not necessary to use unique_violation error handling.